# tikz circuits: how to adjust color of annotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, annotations, circuits

I defined an annotation for make contact symbol. It works well but I have a hard time overriding the color of annotation when I use the symbol.

I checked, the same is the case for light emitting diode featured in the pgfmanual (Version 3.0.1a, Section 47.4.1)

My code and output are below. I want to change the color of the arc showing the closing of S1. Any help will be greatly appreciated...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{circuit declare annotation={swclosed}{}{(4pt,0pt) edge[to path={arc(45:0:12pt)}]()}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        \coordinate (DCpos) at (1,4); 
        \coordinate (ACout) at (1,2); 
        \coordinate (DCneg) at (1,0); 
        \draw [red] (DCpos) to [make contact={swclosed,info={$S1$},red}] (ACout);
        \draw       (ACout) to [make contact={info={$S2$}}] (DCneg);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note it is the arc (edge) I want to paint red, preferably without the clutter of using scope. The intent is to use these images to show sequential operation of a power electronic bridge (with many more switches than shown here)  and use elegant code to paint the path of current conduction red. It is possible to set the color of the arc in the \tikzset line but I prefer to have it adjustable when using the symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{circuit declare annotation={swclosed}{}{(4pt,0pt) edge[#1,to path={arc(45:0:12pt)}]()}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        \coordinate (DCpos) at (1,4); 
        \coordinate (ACout) at (1,2); 
        \coordinate (DCneg) at (1,0); 
        \draw[color=red] (DCpos) to [make contact={swclosed=red,info={[blue]$S1$},red}] (ACout);
        \draw       (ACout) to [make contact={info={$S2$}}] (DCneg);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but my question is about coloring the little arc, not the text label. The color of the text label is actually set by the color attribute of the draw command, and can be overridden using the code you used. It is the arc (edge) that I couldn’t paint red...

Comment: @JovanBebic I see. Sorry! Better now?

Comment: Yes, many thanks. I tried swclosed={red}, and swclosed={color=red} and a bunch of other more convoluted things, but not this. Thank you again!